# Block a matlab script while Simulink runs

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am using a Simulink to collect data real-time from drop tests. The Simulink works great, but my vision is to have a Matlab (v.7.10) script run the simulation for several trials without me having to run over to the computer between drops. This also allows me to pre-process the data before saving it. Both programs work great individually, but I cannot make the Simulink run properly in a script. Using `sim()` returns the error message:

```
    Cannot perform command line simulation of 'acc_DAC' in external mode.
```

Using `set_param(sys, 'SimulationCommand', 'start')` starts the simulation, but does not block the script. The script continues and returns errors because the outputs it is supposed to have don't exist yet. Notably, I read elsewhere that pausing Matlab will pause any simulations as well, though I couldn't get that far myself.

The Simulink runs until the impact is measured, and then stops and outputs accelerometer data to the workspace. What I am asking is:

A) Is there a way to `sim()` run an external, real-time simulation?

B) Is there a good way to make Matlab wait for either Simulink to finish, or variables to exist, without pausing the Simulink?

Comment: I took a shot at [this tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93839-how-can-i-run-a-real-time-simulation-multiple-times-consecutively-from-within-matlab-using-real-time#answer_103190). I got `init_sim` and `start` to work, and the simulation would finish and unload, but the script wouldn't progress any further. My guess is that the `evalin` command I stuck in the end of the Simulink wasn't working properly but have no idea where to go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a week of fiddling with timers and event callbacks, I found that if this is possible, it is absurdly difficult to do. Ultimately I created two functions, one that starts the simulation and one that processes the data output by the first. I have to run them manually, but its not that big of a deal for me. Hopefully this will help someone!

Answer (score 2):

You could try checking the `SimulationStatus` of the running model, and loop until it says `stopped`, although you'll need to be a little careful as there's a chance of entering an infinite loop.

Something like

```
set_param(sys,'SimulationCommand','start');
while ~strcmp(get_param(sys,'SimulationStatus'),'stopped')
    drawnow
end
```

The above will not work in any simulation mode, but may work in external mode.

Comment: It does block the script, but it gets stuck in the loop. I tested it using a dummy Simulink that quits after 2 seconds. The program loops until I ctrl-c, then notifies me that the simulation is completed.